# VBA regex word can't detect text on new line

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that will change the font style of the sentences spoken by one of the speakers in my transcripts. The speaker names are style "Heading 2" and i want to change the interviewers lines to style "Interviewer" as you can probably see from my code snippet.

I've never done VBA or macros before, so this is just what i've pulled together over the past 4-5 hours. I really need this to work as i have 20 transcripts that are really long and to do it manually would take too long.

Any help that you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

I have got the macro to recognise the name of one the speakers but can't get it to ignore that and do the text beneath it. I have posted my code and a screenshot of the document below.

```
Set regExp = New regExp
    Dim objMatch As Match
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim offsetStart As Long
    offsetStart = Selection.Start

    regExp.Pattern = "(Interviewer)([\r\n]+)"
    regExp.Global = True
    regExp.MultiLine = True

    Set colMatches = regExp.Execute(Selection.Text) 'Execute search.
    For Each objMatch In colMatches
        Debug.Print objMatch
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(objMatch.FirstIndex + offsetStart, End:=offsetStart + objMatch.FirstIndex + objMatch.Length)
        myRange.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Interviewer")
    Next
```

[image]

A copy of the file was requested so i've posted it online:
http://www.filedropper.com/stackoverflowexamplefile

If it needs to be uploaded to google drive or something, i can probably do that

Comment: Please could you insert the test text for the regex in the question, not as an image. Exactly as it is in your source.

Comment: it's in a word document

Comment: Copy and paste. Otherwise, we have to type out the above, from the image, and hope we get everything right... despite the fact there may be some hidden character(s) we cannot see.

Comment: i have uploaded and posted the word document itself.

Comment: In the text what is the bit you want to capture?

Comment: "Hello stackoverflow this where the line of the speaker I want to change the font of will be. I’m just typing now to get another line" Basically anything between the two speakers names.

Comment: pssst, it's "Stack Overflow" ;-)

Comment: Could you extract match one from (^[\n\s]\w.*)

Comment: Word should be able to do this with straight Find/Replace, no code required. Ctrl+H to get the dialog box. In the Find box, type Interviewer. Click the "More" button, click "Format", choose "Style" and select the style name. Click in the "Replace" box, don't type anything, click Format, choose Style and get the Style name you want to use. Replace All.

Comment: hi cindy, thank you for your comment. I'm not trying to change the font of the word "Interviewer", i'm trying to change the font of what they said (text underneath), but not change what the participant said (text underneath "Participant")

Comment: i tried (^[\n\s]\w.*) from QHarr and it kind of works. Unfortuantely, it's also changing the participant heading and text underneath

Comment: That is because the first group is what is needed from the regex, not the entire match. I wrote a number of regex which with online testing matches just that information but sadly they all fail when used in Word for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort QHarr.

Comment: I would be interested in a pastebin link to the python script. Thank you.

Comment: When you respond to people in comments you need to "ping" them, otherwise they won't see what you've written. Like this: @user414025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a simple python script using python-docx. It loops through the document checking for the interviewer's name and then just changes the font of the next paragraph. It works perfectly, doing exactly what i needed.

I would like to thank everybody that helped me, it was very much appreciated. I'm going to consider this question answered now. If anyone would like the python script, leave a comment and ill post it.